# threadingモジュールとqueueモジュールの使用によるプログラムの挙動について

Tags: python, マルチスレッド

Pythonについて。

只今、『入門 Python3』を読みながら、
JupyterLabを使ってPythonを学んでいます。
OSはwindows10です。

『11.1.3 スレッド』より。

まずは下のプログラムをご覧ください。
これは、皿洗いと2つのスレッドで動く乾燥担当を、`queue.Queue()`で通信し合って動かすプログラムです。

```
import threading, queue
import time

# 皿を5秒で洗う皿洗い担当を定義する。
def washer(dishes, output) :
    for dish in dishes :
        print('Washing', dish, 'dish')
        time.sleep(5)
        output.put(dish)

# 洗った皿を10秒で乾かす乾燥担当を定義する。
def dryer(input) :
    while True :
        dish = input.get()
        print('Dryer', dish, 'dish')
        time.sleep(10)
        input.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # 洗う皿のリストとキューを定義する。
    dishes = ['salad', 'bread', 'entree', 'dessert']
    dish_queue = queue.Queue()

    # 2つのスレッドを定義する。
    for n in range(2) :
        dryer_thread = threading.Thread(target=dryer, args=(dish_queue,))
        dryer_thread.start()

    # 皿洗いを開始し、キューで通信する。
    washer(dishes, dish_queue)
    dish_queue.join()
```

結果は以下の通りになりました。

```
Washing salad dish
Washing bread dish
Dryer salad dish
Washing entree dish
Dryer bread dish
Washing dessert dish
Dryer entree dish
Dryer dessert dish
```

ここで質問です。
ここでいう『皿洗い担当』を動かしている者の正体はプロセスですか？

尚、言葉や言葉の使い方が正確ではないことがあります。
本文中、気になることがございましたら、何なりとご指摘くださいませ。

Comment: nekketsuuuさんいつもご覧いただきありがとうございます。
yohjpさんもとても詳しい説明ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 皿洗いと2つのスレッドで動く乾燥担当を、queue.Queue()で通信し合って動かすプログラムです。
>   ここでいう『皿洗い担当』を動かしている者の正体はプロセスですか？

求めている答えは「メインスレッド(main thread)」でしょうか？

プログラム実行中のプロセス(process)では、暗黙に生成される1つのメインスレッドが処理を実行していきます。`thread.Thread`メソッドを呼び出すと、メインスレッドとは別の新しいスレッドを生成できます。

Pythonや多くのプログラミング言語では、プログラム上で別スレッドを明示的に生成しない限りはメインスレッドのみで動作するシングルスレッド・プログラムになります。このようなプログラムではプロセスとスレッドは 1:1 の関係となるため、わざわざメインスレッドという概念を持ち出さずに説明されるケースが多いです。